# Laravel : Route::get('login','IndexController@Login')->name('login');

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in laravel. I have use below line for login page,

```
Route::get('login','IndexController@Login')->name('login');
```

here `->name('login')` is necessary to use every route ? and what is a used  of that ?

any idea please share..

Comment: no, its not necessary, its just an alternative for traditional url

Comment: have a look here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes

Comment: Thanks Sohel , but i noticed that  @if (Route::has('login')) is not working without that name

Comment: Thanks for this reference link . I got this concept.

Comment: use can `Request::is('/login')` instead

Answer (score 2):

With the named route you can write something like this in your Blade files

```
<a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="/login">Login</a>
```

So if the URL should change at some point, you don't have to change anything in the blade files if you defined it with the route-helper.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessary for every route, it allows you to name a route / controller action so you can reference it later.

This allows you to do things such as reference a route in a redirect, which is useful in case the URL structure of the route changes, your code will not break because it references the name not the route itself.

```
// Generating URLs...
$url = route('profile');

// Generating Redirects...
return redirect()->route('profile');
```

Find out more in the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the route in different ways with different advantages

Long, without `->name('login')`:

`<a href="{{action('IndexController@Login', ['parameter' => $value])}}">Login</a>`

Short, with `->name('login')`:

`<a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can skip the `->name('login')`. But then if your form you have to specify the URL.

For example, `<form name="some-form" method="POST" action="/login">`

and route will be,

```
Route::get('login','IndexController@Login');
```

But, what if you have 4-5 login forms in different views for the different purpose and in future you decide to rename your `login` URL to `signin`?

Well, then you have to visit each and every form and change their `action` property value.

Instead, if you use `->name('login')` then your form will be,

`<form name="some-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">`

and route will be,

`Route::get('login','IndexController@Login')->name('login');`

Now, if you decide to change your url from `login` to `signin` in your routes file, then you just have to change it their and laravel will take care of your form's url.

like this,

`Route::get('signin','IndexController@Login')->name('login');`

That's it! You don't have to worry about form action value.